# Best way to enqueue CSS and JS in a specific location

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm putting CSS and javascript files in a created directory inside a created directory inside wp-content and my enqueue code is going in an mu-plugin. Due to how I have set-up my wordpress multisite this location is much more ideal for me. So the location of these files are mysite.com/wp-content/uw/

What will be the best replacement for get_template_directory_uri() and get_stylsheet_directory_uri() to get these files?

On http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

I saw a pattern that get_template_directory_uri() and get_stylsheet_directory_uri() has the path outside the brackets:

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js'
```

Whilst the url one has the path inside the brackets with **File** on the outside:

```
plugins_url( '/js/newscript.js' , __FILE__ ),
```

I have come up with a few that all work but would like to check if they are using good practices or if any of them are not good ideas:

Using content_url that includes `__File__`:

```
function test_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test', content_url( '/uw/test.css' , __FILE__ ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_enqueue' );
```

Using network_site_url() that includes `__File__`:

```
function test_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test', network_site_url( 'wp-content/uw/test.css' , __FILE__ ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_enqueue' );
```

Using get_template_directory_uri() but then to back out:

```
function test_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/../../uw/test.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_enqueue' );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My _guess_ would be `content_url()`, but I am not confident what does it return in multisite precisely. Don't have one on hand to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content_url();` seems to be the best option in your case. You want the url of wp-content folder, there is no reason to use other workarounds. Also, accroding with [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/content_url), `content_url()` takes care of current site in a multisite network.

But in your example you are using it a little wrong; `content_url()` doesn't accept a second parameter. It should be  `content_url( '/uw/test.css' )`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, you are right I don't need that __ file__. I'll go with content_url(). By the way what is the _ _File__ used for as it doesn't say what it is in codex.wordpress and it uses it when it uses plugins_url.

Comment: `__FILE__` is a [PHP oredefined constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and its value is the full path of current PHP file including the file name. See docs. If this answer your question, please mark it as accepted.